# if input maybe undefined how to use swig date filter

Tags: node.js, swig-template

I use swig in my nodejs project，when use date filter，I found this：

```
{{t.updateAt|date('Y-m-d H:i:s',-480)}}
NaN-NaN-NaN NaN:NaN:NaN
```

because sometimes t.updateAt is undefined, when this time I need date filter output ''.

so, How can I do?

Answer (score 1):

```
{% if t.updateAt %}
    {{t.updateAt|date('Y-m-d H:i:s',-480)}}
{% endif %}
```